# Locale is not correct when using @Config with language qualifiers. Robolectric 2.3

Tags: robolectric

I want to test locale files using robolectric 2.3. I have two locales en(by default) and sv.
I've tried to use next variants:

```
//1
@Config(qualifiers = "sv")
public void testSVLocalization() {
   Locale.setDefault(new Locale ("sv", "SV"));
   configuration.locale = Locale.getDefault();
   assertThat(configuration.locale).isEqualTo(new Locale ( "sv", "SV"));

   String tabSettingsStr = new MainActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.tab_settings);
   assertEquals(tabSettingsStr, "INSTÄLLNINGAR");
}

//2
...
Locale locale = new Locale("sv", "SV");
Robolectric.shadowOf( startAppActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration() ).setLocale( locale );
Locale.setDefault( locale );
...

//3
@Config(qualifiers = "sv")
public void testSVLocalization() {
Locale locale = resources.getConfiguration().locale;
...}
```

also I've tried `@Config(reportSdk = 20, emulateSdk = 20)` etc. All this methods set locale and when I check it it's shows sv, but on this string `assertEquals(tabSettingsStr, "INSTÄLLNINGAR");` I have an error `org.junit.ComparisonFailure` because this string took from english localization file.

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems like you are experiencing what is described in this issue: 
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/635

Basically, the @Config use will affect the way you load resources in the test directly, but not the way the app's Activities loads these resources. 
To change the locale for your activity, do the following with the resources from that activity, before you test it. That should allow it to pickup the right strings:

```
Robolectric.shadowOf(resources.getConfiguration()).setLocale(locale);
```

Comment: Hmm... What if you do Robolectric.application.getString(R.string.tab_settings)?

Comment: Alex, question not by theme, maybe you know, how to run tests only for one class?

Comment: specifying this in gradle file or exist something like 
./gradle test MyClass

Comment: As far as I know, this is unfortunately not yet possible if you're setup with gradle. You might want to ask the question separately and see if anyone has better suggestions!